# How to make ODOO application responsive to any kind of device?

Tags: odoo-10

I have created the odoo 10 application. I need to make that one responsive.When the resolution changes the alignments are changed. How can I make that one responsive to any device?

Comment: You need to be more clear as to what you want to achieve. Odoo uses Bootstrap, which is responsive if used correctly. To learn more about bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this theme, it makes odoo more responsive and more like the enterprise edition

https://www.odoo.com/apps/themes/10.0/backend_theme_v10/

Answer (score 0):

In tables you have to use width and height in pixels
In forms, labels and fields you can use percentage for width and height